# How to execute query in Joomla 3x sub-controller

Tags: joomla-3.x, cms

I have a simple component that that will be performing CRUD for my mobile app on Joomla site.

These are the structure of my files

```
http://localhost/chichi-server/components/com_chichi/controller.php
http://localhost/chichi-server/components/com_chichi/chichi.php
http://localhost/chichi-server/components/com_chichi/controllers/getdata.php
http://localhost/chichi-server/components/com_chichi/controllers/postdata.php
```

in my chichi.php I have this

```
<?php
  defined('_JEXEC') or die('access dedied');
  jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
  $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
  $controller=JControllerLegacy::getInstance('ChichiMobilePost');
  $controller->execute($input->get('task'));
  $controller->redirect();
```

And in controller.php I have

```
<?php
   defined('_JEXEC') or die('access dedied');
   jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

   class ChichiMobilePostController extends JControllerLegacy{  
          function diplay(){
                echo 'Noting to do';    
              }

          function create(){
                echo 'Welcom to Create';    
              }
     }
```

In my /controllers/getdata.php

```
<?php
 defined('_JEXEC') or die('access dedied');
 jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

class ChichiMobilePostController extends JControllerLegacy{
//GET USER COLLECTIONS  
  function getcollection(){
    //Prevent template from showing
    $app =JFactory::getApplication();
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $userID = $input->post->get('userID');
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    // Create a new query object.
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    try
        {   
            $query
                ->select(array('*'))
                ->from($db->quoteName('#__user'))   
                ->where($db->quoteName('id') .'=' . $userID .'');
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $results = $db->loadAssocList();    
        }
    catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $this->setError('The error message you want');
            return false;
        }   
            echo json_encode(array('collect'=>$results));
            $app->close();
   }        
};
```

My question how do I get query in /controllers/getdata/php to excute

I tried accessing it through

```
 http://localhost/chichi-server/index.php?option=com_chichi&task=getdata.getcollection
```

But I get thi s error "(View not found [name, type, prefix]: get.getcollection, html, chichimobilepostView)"

However If I use

```
     http://localhost/chichi-server/index.php?option=com_chichi&task=create
```

the controller.php is able to output "Welcome to create"

the reason why I am doing this is because there will be a lot post and get request from the mobile app and though I could each process in their own file.

I will be glad if anyone can help. me resolve this, Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to rename your class in /controllers/getdata.php to:
**ChichiMobilePostController*Getdata*** Then Joomla can find the right class and execute getcollection() if you call it via

```
http://localhost/chichi-server/index.php?option=com_chichi&task=getdata.getcollection
```

Comment: Thanks, @Fruppel, I have done it, but it is still outputting

500 (View not found [name, type, prefix]: getdata.getcollection, html, chichimobilepostView)

Comment: Did you spell the class name exactly like in my answer above? Uppercase "G" and "etdata" lowercase?